# Conversion of jpg image to greyscale and how to get attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.0

I am studying on concrete technology, I have jpg image of concrete which is taken by digital camera .I am working with arcgis 10.1 version. I need to convert it into greyscale and get attribute table for further analyasis and classification.How can I get that ? [image]

Comment: Python's scikit-image library is really a slick way to perform digital image processing such as this. http://scikit-image.org/

Answer (score 1):

This is a workflow with ArcGIS 10.3 + Spatial Analyst, so it can be different in your case.

1. Open ArcCatalog and read each band of the `F4Mmj.jpg`(this name came with the attached image when I downloaded it) into ArcGIS (without spatial reference)... actually just drag & drop Band_1, Band_2, Band_3 onto the map window.
2. Open Raster Calculator and run this expression `("F4Mmj.jpg - Band_3" + "F4Mmj.jpg - Band_2" + "F4Mmj.jpg - Band_1") / 3`.
3. `Conversion Tools | From Raster | Raster to ASCII` to export the calculated raster layer out to ASCII text file.

My preference, however, is to use [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/) for image conversion, as it does not require Spatial Analyst license.

1. Open the jpg file by ImageJ, and select `Image | Type | 8-bit` ... this will change the RGB to 8-bit greyscale. (This process also uses the same equation as above, `(R+G+B)/3`).
2. Save it as new image file and give it to ArcGIS.

Comment: Thanks @OnkarKatgaonkar ; As to my 3rd point, I assumed that you needed pixel values. Please let me know if it is not the case. Hopefully this can answer to your previous question: [How to access attribute table of jpg image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245415/how-to-access-attribute-table-of-jpg-image) , too.

Comment: I get greyscale image successfully , but I have some query about pixel value classification, because concrete have cement,fine and coarse aggregate. How can I classify this material through greyscale? I need an unique identity pixel value for each material classification

Comment: @OnkarKatgaonkar Interesting, but I honestly do not know methods through greyscale. Common image classification approach would require RGB spectral signature. You may want to post new question.